# Post scp file transfer unable to do a checksum of the paths of source and destination for comparison

Tags: shell, unix, file-transfer

Post scp file transfer unable to do a checksum of the paths of source and destination for comparison .
I need this to make a scp comparison between the 2 folders i.e., source and destination
Also I can make use only of cksum for comparison

Script1.sh

```
Username@hostname: Scp username@hostname2:~/folder1/*.csv ~/folder2/

Cksum folder1.csv > abs.csv
```

Therefore I need the checksum of the destination path too.

I have tried this without using a script:
1)

```
Username@hostname1: sftp username@hostname2
Sftp> cksum ~/folder1/d1.csv 
Invalid command
```

2. 

```
username@hostname1# cksum username@hostname2:~/folder2/*.csv

Cksum: input file username@hostname2:~/folder2/*.csv no such file or directory..
```

Please note I have the path and files present in username@hostname2..

Is there a way to find and store the checksum of another server path(destination) for comparison.

Comment: Your post is really hard to read. You should put backticks (`) around command line input/output and code. Use triple backticks (```) for multi-line blocks.

Comment: **1** The command is `cksum`, not `Cksum`.  Capital letters matter.  **2** `scp` is used to copy files from, or to, a remote server.  **3** `sftp` is the same.  **4** to run a command on another remote server, you need to use `ssh`.  With `ssh` you can connect to the other server and run `cksum`.  **5** If you have the proper rights to run `scp` you will be able to run `ssh`.

Comment: Thank you this is useful.  However, username@hostname1# ssh $1@$2 'cd ~/folder1 | cksum *.csv >  ABC.csv' for this the cd goes to the home path. Whereas I want to go to an specific folder using ~ . And do cksum.  And save it in a file which I can use in the parent server username@hostname1.